# How can I revert a control change to my "A" key?

Tags: dont-starve, keyboard

I changed my <kbd>a</kbd> key to "Select" so now I can’t re-change <kbd>a</kbd> to "Left" due to the fact that when I try to click any options on the right, it moves to the add on the left.

Comment: Try going into settings and revert controls to default. I'm assuming this is on PC.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Arqade. I did my best to try and edit your question to be a bit more clear, but I was unsure of what key it was that you changed and needed reverting. You might want to double check the edit and also clarify more about what the problem is wrt why you can't change it back. Thanks

Comment: +CrabtasticGoat How do I go to settings